# Appending a column in a pandas DataFrame based on a different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two DataFrames:

```
df1

       A   B
    0  8   x
    1  3   y
    2  1   x
    3  2   z
    4  7   y

    and

df2    
       A   B
    0  x   hey
    1  y   there
    2  z   sir
```

I am trying to append `df1['B']` based on `df2['B']` so that my desired output would be:

```
df3

       A   B
    0  8   hey
    1  3   there
    2  1   hey
    3  2   sir
    4  7   there
```

Is there a built in method for doing this kind of transformation?  I was experimenting with something similar to this, but I could not get it to function properly:

```
for x in df1['B']:
    if df2['A'] == x:
        df1['B'].append.df2['B']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll want a simple merge:

```
In [10]: df1.merge(df2, left_on='B', right_on='A')
Out[10]:
   A_x B_x A_y    B_y
0    8   x   x    hey
1    1   x   x    hey
2    3   y   y  there
3    7   y   y  there
4    2   z   z    sir
```

And if you'd like to keep the order of the index:

```
In [11]: df1.reset_index().merge(df2, left_on='B', right_on='A').set_index('index').sort_index()
Out[11]:
       A_x B_x A_y    B_y
index
0        8   x   x    hey
1        3   y   y  there
2        1   x   x    hey
3        2   z   z    sir
4        7   y   y  there
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set column `A` as an index to look-up values in column `B`:

```
>>> df1.B = df2.set_index('A').loc[df1.B,'B'].values
>>> df1
   A      B
0  8    hey
1  3  there
2  1    hey
3  2    sir
4  7  there

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```